# Date format problem having datatype is object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset that contains a date column in the format of "DD/MM/YYYY"

I have to slice and order by year only, but I am unable to slice this, because this date column is having the data type "object".

Please suggest me what I have to do.

Comment: There are no columns in python in any strict sense. Presumably you have a dataframe. Use `pandas.to_datetime()`

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['column_name']).dt.year`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Best bet is **`datetime.datetime.strptime()`** function:

Since you have a datetime.datetime object with you, *Year can be extrected using .year attribute* :

## Datetime Code Explanation :

```
# Import Datetime from Datetime Package :

from datetime import datetime

# Initialise the String Value :

string = "2018-27-12 19:21:10"

# Using strptime method from datetime 
# Convert the String to Date in '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' Format :
# Note : %m denotes 'Month' and %M denotes 'Minute' :

date_time = datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Extract the Year using .year Attribute :

print(date_time.year)
```

## Output :

```
2018
```

Edit : This can also be achieved using **pandas.to_datetime** method